# How to answer the following question "Was mögen Sie alles nicht?"

Tags: modal-verb, question, negation

The question is basically saying what you never like to do, right?
So, I will answer

> Ich mag nicht so viel fernsehen.

I basically want to say I don't like watching a lot of TV.

Are the position of the word *nicht* and the conjugation of the verbs correct?

Comment: I was tempted to VTC as proofreading, but I see one fundamental issue that should be adressed - see my answer below. (Possibly temporary, but too long for a comment.)

Answer (score 6):

While your suggested *answer* is gramatically correct and idiomatic, you might want to go back to the *question*:

> Was mögen Sie alles nicht?

→ *alles* being the operative word here. If you ask for *alles*, you are essentially expecting a list, in this case a list of things you dislike. (Note that a list may contain only one element, but you need to understand the intent of the question.)

There is no hint of *never* implied and it is not restricted to activities unless this can be inferred from the context, which we don’t have here. In plain English:

> What are the things you dislike? / What are your dislikes?

You may use your answer if watching TV excessively is your sole dislike, but much more common would be something along the lines of:

> Ich mag nicht viel fernsehen, keine weichgekochten Eier und keine besserwisserischen Antworten.

Answer (score 3):

You misinterpreted the question. This is a correct German question:

> Was mögen Sie alles?

It means: »What are all things that you like?« Or shorter: »What do you like?« This question asks for a list of things that you like.

If you want to ask for the things you don't like, you must use this negation:

> Was mögen Sie alles nicht?

It means: »What are all things that you don't like?« Or shorter: »What do you dislike?«

You can ask both questions without »alles«:

> Was mögen Sie?
>   Was mögen Sie nicht?

And you would expect almost the same answers. But the word »alles« puts the focus more to the fact, that the questioner wants to know *ALL* things you like or dislike, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue pointed out by others, namely that the question expects a list of things, I want to address the suboptimal wording of your answer.

What you probably wanted to say was:

> I don’t enjoy watching TV that much.

But what you ended up saying was:

> I don’t want to watch that much TV.

The *viel* in the answer can only be used to express the excess of watching, i.e. watching *lots* of TV. Saying you don’t like it as much would be:

> Ich mag nicht so gerne fernsehen.

Or:

> Ich mag Fernsehen nicht so gerne.

Personally, I would prefer the second one. Note the *gerne* which conveys the enjoyment (lots of enjoyment, if you insist) and which is also negated by *nicht.*